# Numpy: Sum of 1D array for index i < j

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm trying to figure out how to most efficiently (with NumPy) calculate the following expression for a 1D ndarray (in this case, *f*):

[image]

I imagine I could do something like:

```
f = [ 1, 3, 2, 3, 7, 5, 2]
for i in range(0, len(f-1)):
    for j in range(0, len(f-2)):
        ...
```

But that would mean that I'll have to have a conditional loop for every element in the list, if I understand this correctly. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage numpy broadcasting:

```
f = np.array([ 1, 3, 2, 3, 7, 5, 2])
np.triu(f[:,None]-f).sum()
```

or equally:

```
np.tril(f-f[:,None]).sum()
```

output:

```
-24
```

Comment: This conveniently uses the fact that the values in the excluded positions will be zero and will not impact on the sum. But suppose that there is a generic operation for which that is not the case. Is there a way that you can efficiently extract a 1-d array containing (in some order) the values of `f[i]-f[j]` only for the values of `i,j` for which `i<j` (i.e. length 21 in this example)?

Comment: @alani There are various ways to do that. Here is one: `(f[:,None]-f)[np.triu_indices(f.size,1)]`

Comment: @alani You are welcome :) Note that I even included the diagonal in the selection since diagonal in this specific case is 0. in a generic case, you can even choose the offset using the argument of either of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one

```
f = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
combined = 0
for i in range(0, len(f)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(f)):
        combined += f[i]-f[j]
```

you use i as the starting point of your inner loop. This way you don't need the if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use Numpy but if you want you could simply use list slicing and do something like this

```
def partial_sum(lst,i, j):
    return sum(lst[i:j])
```